# Listener Class change text label on my form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following class in C#:

```
public class LeapEventListener : Listener
{
    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New Frame");
        // process frame data...
    }

    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized");
    }

    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        //If using gestures, enable them:
        controller.EnableGesture(Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_CIRCLE);
    }

    //Not dispatched when running in debugger
    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
    }
}
```

and call it on form load:

```
controller.AddListener(listener);
```

I know that changing a label from class is not a good idea and violates some programming paradigms but how can I change a label text instead of Console.WriteLine ?

Comment: What type is `Controller` (what namespace)? It doesn't seem to be [`System.Web.Mvc.Controller`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), as that one doesn't have an `EnableGesture` or an `AddListener` method.

Comment: Leap type, is about leapmotion.com

Comment: Also, what is meant by "changing a label from class"? I do not understand that phrase. As C# is object-oriented, you are virtually always in a class with whatever you do. Hence, I have no idea how you could possibly "change a label" without a class, or why it would be a better idea than doing it "from class".

Comment: For example I need something like this: label1.Text = "Initialised";

Comment: Yes, I got that much - but what's the problem with writing just that instead of `Console.WriteLine("Initialized");`?

Comment: Because I use windows forms with a form with a big label.

Comment: So what's the problem? Just assign the text to your big label. Why is that "not a good idea"? What programming paradigms exactly are violated?

Comment: You cannot access ui from a separated class. You can only access ui from the current form class.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I'm guessing they mean that the class updating the label is not the form the label is held on, which is normally against best practise as it couples the class and the form and adds a responsibility to the class which is now controlling part of the view.

Comment: If the listener is instantiated in your `Form` you could define and fire an event. Or you could pass the Label (maybe "as Control") into the Listener... Alltogether this smells a little :-)

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Observer pattern. Make LeapEventListener the subject with an interface that calls handlers when something that needs to be handled happens. Your form can be a handler and respond to the event by changing the label's text.

Comment: @JamesBarrass: Ok, although if the (or at least a) point of the listener implementation is updating the view, this doesn't seem problematic. After all, the point of inheriting from an abstract base class (such as a listener base class) is usually to provide a specialized implementation coupled to a specific other component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the "good practice" ways.

First, modify your class as follows

```
public class LeapEventListener : Listener
{
    private string status = string.Empty;

    public string Status { get { return status; } }

    public event EventHandler StatusChanged;

    private void SetStatus(string value)
    {
        if (value == null) value = string.Empty;
        status = value;
        var handler = StatusChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        SetStatus("New Frame");
        // process frame data...
    }

    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        SetStatus("Initialized");
    }

    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        SetStatus("Connected");
        //If using gestures, enable them:
        controller.EnableGesture(Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_CIRCLE);
    }

    //Not dispatched when running in debugger
    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        SetStatus("Disconnected");
    }
}
```

All I did was to add a public readonly property, a private method to set it and a public property change event.

Then simply add the following line in your form load (of course after the `listener` is created):

```
yourLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", listener, "Status");
```

and you are done.

**UPDATE:** As per you comments:

(A) If you want to append to a `RichTextBox`. Data binding works only with properties, so in this case you can simply attach an event handler, like this:

```
listener.StatusChanged += (_sender, _e) =>
{
    yourRichTextBox.AppendText(listener.Status);
};
```

(B) If listener methods are called from a non UI thread, then forget about data binding, use event handler like above, but in a slightly different way:

```
Action onStatusChanged = () =>
{
    // Whatever UI element you want to update
    yourLabel.Text = listener.Status;
    yourRichTextBox.AppendText(listener.Status);
};
listener.StatusChanged += (_sender, _e) =>
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
        Invoke(onStatusChanged);
    else
        onStatusChanged();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! But why `RichTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("AppendText", listener, "Status");` does not work?

Comment: @IonVasile Because `AppendText` is a method, and data binding works only with properties.

Comment: I see, so I cannot append to a richtextbox what listener do?

Comment: Also when I click run I get: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'label1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on._ but with Ctrl F5 works great.

Comment: @IonVasile (1) You can, but not using data binding, just attaching to the event. (2) You'll have this problem with any of the suggested implementations if the methods of the listener are called from a non UI thread.

Comment: @IonVasile See the updated answer how you can handle those cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need to couple your listener implementation to a label:

```
public class LeapEventListener : Listener
{
    public LeapEventListener(Label lbl)
    {
        if (lbl == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lbl");
        }

        this.lbl = lbl;
    }

    private readonly Label lbl;

    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        lbl.Text = "New Frame";
        // process frame data...
    }

    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Initialized";
    }

    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Connected";
        //If using gestures, enable them:
        controller.EnableGesture(Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_CIRCLE);
    }

    //Not dispatched when running in debugger
    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        lbl.Text = "Disconnected";
    }
}
```

When instantiating the listener, pass the label from your form.

EDIT: I'd argue this is clean design in that the `Listener` base class and your form are weakly coupled. The only connection between those classes is centralized in this one `LeapEventListener` class, which acts as the bridge.

If you are doing more (depending on what is meant by "process frame data") in this listener, you might want to add an additional layer of inheritance that only does the work and invokes an abstract method for displaying the status:

```
public abstract class LeapEventListener : Listener
{
    protected abstract void DisplayStatus(string message);

    public override void OnFrame(Controller controller)
    {
        DisplayStatus("New Frame");
        // process frame data...
    }

    public override void OnInit(Controller controller)
    {
        DisplayStatus("Initialized");
    }

    public override void OnConnect(Controller controller)
    {
        DisplayStatus("Connected");
        //If using gestures, enable them:
        controller.EnableGesture(Gesture.GestureType.TYPE_CIRCLE);
    }

    //Not dispatched when running in debugger
    public override void OnDisconnect(Controller controller)
    {
        DisplayStatus("Disconnected");
    }
}

public class LabelLeapEventListener : LeapEventListener
{
    public LabelLeapEventListener(Label lbl)
    {
        if (lbl == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lbl");
        }

        this.lbl = lbl;
    }

    private readonly Label lbl;

    protected override void DisplayStatus(string message)
    {
        lbl.Text = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: @IonVasile You're other option is to have it call a method on the form and then decouple by having the event on an interface which the form implements and then assign the form to be the implementation of that interface. This would allow you to assign a logging view / network view / ui view to the listener. Which may be a great feature - or depending on your project a waste of time resulting in your "Go To Definition" searching landing you in an interface everytime for no real benefit.

Comment: @IonVasile: I have updated my answer with some further thoughts on this.